# Secondary Foreign Key that increments for each association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Is there anyway to have a foreign key that increments based on the number of `comments` in a particular `post` (so the user doesn't see the number of comments based on `comment_id`)?

For example each post's comments should start with the index 1:

```
Post.find(1).comments.first.relative_id # 1
Post.find(2).comments.first.relative_id # 1
```

This makes it possible for a route such as:

```
# The total number of comments is hidden because comment_id is not used
get 'post/:post_id/comments/:relative_id' => 'comments#show'

Example:
/post/1/comments/1 would refer to Comment.find(1)
/post/2/comments/1 would refer to Comment.find(2)
```

Comment: Would the url `post/comments/1` refer to the comment on Post #1 or the comment on Post #2?

Comment: Could be either one. Sorry the route is actually:

`get 'post/:post_id/comments/:relative_id' => 'comments#show'` I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you make your url of the form `post/:post_id/comments/:comment_id` so that they are unambiguous.

You can still use an incrementing number in your URL's, I would look at something like the `acts_as_list` gem (https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list)

You probably still want to use the normal id internally but you can use the `position` in url's just make sure that it is indexed in your database.